# Distributed locks with queue

Tags: c#, distributed-system, locks

I have a single instance application that need to be moved in order that can run from multiple servers for performance reasons.

When a specific operation is executed the software need to be sure that the other instances was not working on the same operation.

I made some tests with Redis distributed locks but have some problems: also trying for 10 seconds with a retry each 50 msec sometimes the software is unlucky and is not able to acquire a lock because in the meanwhile other instances that started later was able to acquire the lock.

Exists some distributed locks services that are able to manage queue? Basically what I need is that when the software was not able to acquire the lock because is used by another instance can keep the priority and been the first to be served when the lock was released.

Of course my last solution can be write a custom software that can manage locks with queue, but I'm trying to understand if already exists some other solutions.

Comment: Is a (central/clusterized) relational database infeasible? Distributed locks are a pain

Comment: You could look at exclusive queues provided by a messaging system like RabbitMQ. They can be used as a distributed lock.

Comment: I'm also considering to use "sp_getapplock" on SQL server, I made some test and seems fit my need but I'm a bit worried about CPU load.

Comment: The solution that I will choose need to be as fast as possible because currently, I need to replace a lock(object) made in c#, so almost any choice will be slower. I have the possibility to use also MySql with in-memory tables because my project need to store some data centralized (now are in the cache of the application)

Answer (score 3):

> Exists some distributed locks services that are able to manage queue? Basically what I need is that when the software was not able to acquire the lock because is used by another instance can keep the priority and been the first to be served when the lock was released.

Do you need the hard canonical way or can you allow some simplification?

The hard canonical way is the one you study at university and requires a lot of custom software. I am a bit rusty, but in a distributed system you must use an **ordered** and **reliable** message delivery to be barely sure to keep the FIFO order. A service bus or a queue can guarantee to deliver messages in order, but then in order to hold a distributed lock you need to implement **consensus**, which is extremely hard. After that, you must deal with all sorts of implementation flaws that are very common in software science.

A consensus algorithm, leader or leaderless, involves a lot of communication to make sure all peers receive the same messages in the same order and are able to determine who is the owner of the lock, even without sending an explicit lock signal after release (which is explicit). Of course, the service bus must deliver the message to the node self before the node acquires the lock.

Think of a distributed algorithm like: the node is listening on the bus. When the first lock request comes in, node knows that the sender is the owner of the lock. Node awaits for other lock requests and puts those in a local queue. When the original holder sends a release message, every node knows the lock owner is the one that sent the second lock request. In order to acquire the lock, a node sends a message to the broadcast, and waits until it receives it to know its queue position. When it received `n` release messages, it knows it's their turn.

### Make it practical

You could use a relational database. I don't have knowledge of your scenario, but a single point of failure could be mitigated by some kind of clustering, <strike>master-slave</strike> primary-secondary, etc.

SQL databases are f***in great at handling concurrency. They ensure that transactions are executed in a consistent order. If your application uses a database table as queue, you will see that it's very easy to run SQL `UPDATE LOCKS SET IS_LOCKED = 1 WHERE LOCK_ID = ? AND IS_LOCKED = 0` without clashes. To handle the queue, put the node name in another table and make sure you `ORDER BY` a SQL sequence.

Comment: See https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: Yes, use a database is a good way, my application currently uses Sql Server but I'm planning to add also MySql to store some data with in-memory tables. The only problem is that I need that my software will make polling in case the application is currently locked (but maybe this can happen with a lot of solutions)